# Sorting LinkedHashMap date in milliseconds issue in Kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

Here is my what i am doing to sort my `LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<Image>>`

```
val sorted = mediumGroups.toSortedMap(if (sortDescending) compareByDescending { it } else compareBy { it })
```

The string in the LinkedHashMap is the date in currentTimeMillis

the problem i am having is when the date is before 1000000000000

> Sat 8 September 2001 21:46:40

those dates are 1 less digit so it sorts them to top.

Is there a way to sort properly without having to convert my LinkedHashMap to a Int instead of String?

Comment: Write a custom comparator instead of sort by descending.  But performance wise-  to get what you want, you're going to have to convert those strings to ints at runtime anyway at a high cost and multiple times, so you'd be better off converting them to ints once when they come into the system.  Why were you ever storing date/time stamps as strings?  They're ints for a reason-  so you can compare them by using < and >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GabeSechan pointed there is the comment you cannot properly compare number in string representation, performance wise the best way will be to initially store timestamps as `Long` and then default comparator will work, and it will be more efficient to compare `Long` rather `String`.
If you want the easiest solution just use `it.toLong()`

```
mediumGroups.toSortedMap(if (sortDescending) compareByDescending { it.toLong() } else compareBy { it.toLong() })
```